# Loading module positions in bootstrap tabs doesn't work

Tags: joomla-3.x, bootstrap

I'm trying to use **Bootstrap Tabs** and I'm trying to **load a moduleposition in each tab**.

The module positions work when not in tabs, but when in tabs the first and last tabs work, but the others only load things which are not loadposition.

If I remove the last tab, only the first one works.

There are no errors in the console.

Comment: Please provide some code or a link to your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem turned out to be caused by SEBLOD and its templating.  I was not aware that this could have been the case, I have since learned a lot more about SEBLOD.

The solution to use Bootstrap Tabs (or NoNumber Tabs) with SEBLOD lists is to add the following CSS which will fix the height issue.

```
.cck_module_list div div div div { height: auto !important; }
```

And yes, I know that CSS looks stupid :)

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling the 'Prepare content' option in the module settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I agree this would be the issue in a lot of other situations but in this case it is on in all modules.  They work normally, they just don't work when in bootstrap tabs.  I tried loading NoNumber tabs and it had an identical issue.  The issue appears to be with the module - SEBLOD list modules.